# Regex Expression for CheckStyle is ignoring minimum property

Tags: regex, checkstyle

Based on http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_regexp.html

I am trying to find hard coded occurance of same strings. Which are repeated.

It returns me all the lines that have hardcoded string but it does not seem to care about "minimum" property.

I just need one which occured more then once. Here is my custom check

```
    < module name="RegexpSinglelineJava">
        < property name="format" value="&quot;*&quot;"/>
        < property name="minimum" value="2"/>
    < /module>
```

Thanks

Comment: In the link you posted, read again what `minimum` does. It has nothing to do with finding equal strings, it just counts the number of matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `minimum` property is not a count of equal strings:

```
minimum       The minimum number of matches required in each file.
```

You could use an expression like:

```
(?s)("(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*")(?=.*?\1)
```

With `RegexpMultiline`. Altho that may not be very efficient.

Something like:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
  <property name="format" value='(?s)("(?:[^"\\]+|\\.)*")(?=.*?\1)'/>
</module>
```